# SDWebImage resize image

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, resize-image

I am using the SDWebImage library in order to download and cache images. In my application, each user has an avatar which can be displayed in different shapes and sizes (circle, square ...).
Right now i am downloading the image, and when i get it i resize it according to the image view size.
But i think this approach is inefficient and specially when scrolling in a table view.
Is there a different approach (concerning SDWebImage) that allows me to get the image in the desired size without having to resize it my self ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image once and store it in a cache (SDImageCache). Then load it from this cache. There is no way to get the image in the desired size without having to resize it yourself, unless such image of desired size exists on the server.

Comment: Is it a best practice to save the same image for different sizes ?

Comment: @rokridi If you want fast scrolling it is the only practice.

Comment: according to your, each time i want to show an avatar in a different size i have to download it first (if not found locally) and resize it before caching it.You mean that i can have the same image (in cache) but in different sizes. Am i correct ?

Comment: @rokridi Yes, you first download the max size image, then store it in the cache f.e. with name "someimage_original.png", then resize it and cache it with the name "someimage_thumb.png".